# Is there anyway to format negative numbers in red in a table in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, conditional-formatting, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, text-formatting

I have tables of data and I want the negative numbers to show up in red (similar to what you would do in Excel). Does PowerPoint have this capability?

[image: Red negative numbers in Excel]

Answer (score 1):

This macro will format the named table on the active slide to have negative numbers in red and within parentheses.  I have not found a way to format the table manually.

```
Sub FormatTheTable() 
            Dim x As Long
            Dim y As Long

        With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Table 540").Table  ' Table 540 is the name of the shape/table

            For x = 2 To .Rows.Count     'Starts on the second row to ignore titles
            For y = 2 To .Columns.Count   'Starts on the second column to ignore titles
                If .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.HasText Then  'Checks that the cell has text

                    If CDbl(Val(.Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)) < 0 Then 'converts text to a double and evaluates it to be less than zero
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CDbl(Val(.Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)) * -1 'multiply by negative 1 to remoe the negative sign
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Change font color to red
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True  'Makes the font bold
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "(" & .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ")"  'Adds parentheses
                    Else
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' makes the non-negative numbers font color black
                        .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True   'Makes the font bold
                    End If
                End If
            Next    ' Column
            Next    ' Row
        End With    ' otbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables were created in Excel, it would be easy to do. Go to the original Excel file, select all the numbers and change the format of the numbers so that the negative numbers are red.

Otherwise, you can select each number you need to change and change the text color.

I believe there is also the possibility of changing the formatting of the number to do the same as Excel, but I don't have access to the program at home.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use conditional formatting in Excel. Select the cell where you want to use conditional formatting (**Home** -> **Conditional Formatting** -> **New Rule** -> **Format only cells that contain** -> *Choose Cell value less than zero and format it to red*) to turn all the numbers less than zero to be red. Now when you paste the table in power point it will show negative numbers as red.